# user32.dll FindWindowEx получение текста

Tags: c#, winapi

Как я могу получить текст с `lable` окна другой программы используя user32.dll? 
Пытаюсь найти но не получается.

```
    int i = 0;
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var m = FindWindow("WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d", null);
        var child = FindWindowEx(m, IntPtr.Zero + i, null, null);
        textBox2.Text += i + GetWindowTextRaw(child);
        i++;

    }
```

Вот что "говорит" Inspector по клику на lable:

```
How found:  Mouse move (483,319)
hwnd=0x00010AE0 32bit class="WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d" style=0x56010000 ex=0x10000
ChildId:    0
Interfaces: IEnumVARIANT IOleWindow
Impl:   Remote native IAccessible
Name:   "Command History:"
Value:  [null]
Role:   client (0xA)
State:  focusable (0x100000)
Location:   {l:24, t:163, w:1242, h:250}
Selection:  
Description:    [null]
Kbshortcut: [null]
DefAction:  [null]
Help:   [null]
HelpTopic:  ""
ChildCount: 12
Window: 0x10AE0
FirstChild: none : window : focusable
LastChild:  none : window : focusable
Next:   [null]
Previous:   [null]
Left:   [null]
Up: [null]
Right:  [null]
Down:   [null]
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   none : window : focusable
    none : window : focused,focusable
    "Project : " : window : focusable
    "1126F1_9363262_40A" : window : focusable
    "Run" : window : focusable
    "Stop" : window : focusable
    "Serial #" : window : focusable
    "1P11321126F1#2PG#SJ1641700018" : window : focusable
    none : window : focusable
    "TS128L " : window : focusable
    "TS128L " : window : focusable
    none : window : focusable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя несколько дней разобрался. Может кому пригодится.

```
void FindWindow(){
        var hWndParent = FindWindow("WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d", null);
        FindChild(hWndParent);
    }
void FindChild(IntPtr hWndParent){
    EnumChildWindows(hWndParent, new EnumWindowsProc(( hWnd, lParam ) => {
        if (GetParent(hWnd) != hWndParent){                                                                     
            return true;
           }
        FindChild(hWnd);
        if(GetText(hWnd).StartsWith("1P11321126F1#2PG#")){
             if(label1.InvokeRequired){
                label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                label1.Text = GetText(hWnd).Trim();})); 
            }
        }
        return true;
        }), IntPtr.Zero);
  }
string GetText(IntPtr hWnd){          
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(WM_GETTEXTLENGTH + 100000);
        string text =  SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH + 100000, sb).ToString();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

---

```
    #region user32.dll
    delegate bool EnumWindowsProc ( IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool EnumWindows ( EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool EnumChildWindows ( IntPtr hWndParent,  EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetParent ( IntPtr hWnd );
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetClassName ( IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowTextLength ( IntPtr hWnd );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam[Out] StringBuilder lParam);

    const int  WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;
    const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    #endregion
```